# What all hardwares can be used for NFC Pairing?

Tags: nfc

as we all know, there are NFC facility in mobile phones now-a-days. It works on the principle related to induction. Once the paring is made, data gets transferred via WiFi or Bluetooth. We might remember Nokia N8 and nokia C7 devices. When it was launched, it did not have NFS, but with an update to symbian Anna, it got that facility. So, what is the hardware that is used for paring to initiate data transfer?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use NFC the device needs to have one of the NFC chips/chipsets.

The C7 uses the NXP PN544, which was one of the [first NFC chips](http://www.nxp.com/news/press-releases/2009/05/nxp-propels-nfc-with-world-s-first-industry-standard-chip.html). NXP is a spin off from Phillips.

If you want to see all of the components for NFC look at the disassemble C7 [here](http://www.nfcworld.com/2011/02/13/35913/)

On top of the Chip you need the NFC software stack, which is what was provided as part of the Symbian Anna.